# Mover linha para outra tabela no banco de dados PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho uma tabela de filmes no meu site que tem a opção de editar e excluir.
Estou com dificuldade para excluir o filme da minha tabela.
O que eu quero fazer é:
Quando clicar em excluir, ele mover a linha para uma outra tabela do mesmo tipo, fazendo de backup. Após ele mover, excluir a linha da tabela atual.

O quer não estou conseguindo fazer é passar o id do campo no link. Quando eu clico no botão para "excluir" da tabela, ele não passa o valor desejado, passando somente o valor 2.

Segue meu código:

Botao

```
<a href="painel_adm_deletefilme.php?idFilme='.$dados['idFilme'].'"><input class="btn btn-danger" name="excluirFilme" value="Sim" class="btn btn-danger"></input></a>
```

painel_adm_deletefilme

```
<?php
```

session_start();
   include_once 'conectaBanco.php';

```
$id = $_GET["idFilme"];

$envia = "INSERT INTO filmesDelet (idFilme, filme, descricao, genero, anoLancamento, faixaEtaria, trailer) 
SELECT idFilme, filme, descricao, genero, anoLancamento, faixaEtaria, trailer 
from filmes where idFilme = '$id'";

$insere_bd = $conecta->prepare($envia);

if($insere_bd->execute()){
    echo 'sucesso';
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

?>

O código não retorna nenhum erro. Ele entra direto no if do sucesso, sendo que não foi passado a tabela a linha desejada. Sempre que eu clico para "excluir" ele passa o id de valor 2.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas porque todo esse trabalho? É realmente necessário mover para outra tabela?
Porque você não cria uma coluna "excluido (bool)" e marca como true quando o cliente exlcuir o registro, depois mostrar apenas os filmes não excluidos "where exluidos = false"

Mas se você realmente quiser "copia e colar" mantendo o mesmo ID, primeiro você deve conferir se o seu ID do banco não está auto incremento e depois basta carregar os dados e dar insert na tabela de backup.

Vlw!

Comment: Vou fazer como voce falou, setar um atributo na tabela e mostrar de acordo com o valor booleano.

Answer (score 0):

Essa parte do código não parece correta:

```
<a href="painel_adm_deletefilme.php?idFilme='.$dados['idFilme'].'">
```

Você colocou código php direto no html.
Acho que funcionaria se trocasse por isso:

```
<a href="painel_adm_deletefilme.php?idFilme=<?=$dados['idFilme'];?>">
```

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, esse trecho de código esta dentro de um echo foreach, por isso nao precisei abrir a tag de php.

Comment: Mas quando você passa o mouse sobre o link não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro na barra de status que mostra o caminho do link?